# Get values from a column of a csv file

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm trying to read an .csv file using OpenCsv library. Now I'm encountering the following problem:

I have this csv file

```
C1;C2;C3;C4      Header
A11;A12;A13;A14  Body
A21;A22;A23;A24  
A31;A32;A33;A34
...;...;...;...
...;...;...;...
```

Now I would want to get all values (without duplicates) from column C2 for example. Summarizing I want to find a way to do getValues("C3") and i want to get A13,A23;a33. 
Can openCsv help me?
Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suppose

1 is id
2 is price
3 is username ....

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String line;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:/test.csv"));
   int i=0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);

           StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
 if(i==0)
  {
    i++;
    continue; // skip headers
  }
           while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {



            Integer id = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString());
            Double price = Double.parseDouble(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString());
            String username = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("\nId : " + id);
            sb.append("\nPrice : " + price);
            sb.append("\nUsername : " + username);
            sb.append("\n*******************\n");

            System.out.println(sb.toString());
           }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another way to do this?

You can use [CSVParser](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) from apache commons and during iteration of each record add the value to the [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). At the end you will have all the unique values in the set. E.g.

```
Set<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<>();
File csvData = new File("/path/to/csv");
 CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(csvData, CSVFormat.RFC4180);
 for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser) {
     uniqueValues.add(csvRecord.get(2))
 }
```